# python - read email from postfix in python on linux

Tags: python, linux, postfix-mta

I'm very new to postfix and python. I've setup postfix on Ubuntu and have configured the `main.cf` with `mailbox_command = /home/someuser/test.py`

test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, MySQLdb

email_input = sys.stdin
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="user", 
                     passwd="password",
                     db="test")

cur = db.cursor()

sql = "insert into postfix (value) values (%s)"
cur.execute(sql, (email_input,))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

I was expecting the content of the email to be inserted into the field but instead I ended up with `<open file '<stdin>', mode 'r' at 0x7f018b3b40c0>`

How do I get the raw email string from what seems to be that memory address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.stdin` is an object of type `TextIOWrapper` and `cur.execute` is expecting a string. You need to instruct `sys.stdin` to read input and return the string representing it. Use either `readline` or `readlines` depending on what you're trying to do.

```
cur.execute(sql, (sys.stdin.readlines(),))
```